# How to make XHTML "table" with fluid table rows

Tags: html, css, layout, quirks-mode

Basically i want to be able to make a a grid of boxes, where i can align text at the top middle and bottom of each box, and have the boxes on the same row resize when text in another box on its row pushes it down.

If you look at this HTML 4 code, it achieves what i want to be able to do, but id like to be able to achieve this with the XHTML 1.0 doctype.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#apDiv1 {
        width:200px;
        height:100%;
            border:1px solid #000;
}

#apDiv1 table{
        width:200px;
        height:100%;
            border:1px solid #000;
}
-->
</style>
<div id="apDiv1"><table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr><td>blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td height="100%">blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah</td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr><td>blah</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="100%"><p>blahfhfh</p>
          <p>dfhdf</p>
          <p>h</p>
          <p>dfh</p>
          <p>df</p>
          <p>h</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah</td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr><td>blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td height="100%">blah</td></tr>
      <tr><td>blah</td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="100%"><p>blahfhfh</p>
          <p>dfhdf          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td><table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="100%">blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td><table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="100%">blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="100%">blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td><table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="100%">blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td><table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="100%">blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your issue is not related to XHTML at all. It's more of Quirks mode vs Standards mode and (X)HTML Strict vs (X)HTML Transitional.

Answer (score 1):

There's [a cross-browser way to achieve grid using CSS](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) with `display:inline-block`, however it may not be as flexible as you'd like (and code is pretty ugly if you want to support Firefox 2).

The issue you might have with “XHTML” is that CSS without emulation of IE5 bugs (which you get when you don't use DOCTYPE or use one of old/incomplete ones) restricts when you can use `height:100%`.

Height in percent doesn't work if parent element has `auto` height, and by default almost every HTML element has auto height. You have to set explicit height on all parent elements of the table:

```
html,body,#apDiv1 {
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, make your document have the DOCTYPE of HTML 4.01 strict and make it validated first, using http://validator.w3.org

then, you can change the DOCTYPE to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

and then re-validate it.  If there is any problem or things that behave differently, you can ask about the specific question here.

Comment: The code posted here doesn't validate due to height being set.